# split a string but keep type

Tags: python, split

I have a csv line where each element of the line can be of different types (`int`, `str`, `float`,...). e.g.

```
"today is", 10, "tomorrow is" 20
```

I also have a sql query of the type:

```
ramble varchar,
date int,
ramble varchar,
date int,
```

My goal is to find if any input text complies with the sql schema. To do that I would like to, in python:

1. split the input text, and
2. check whether the type of each element matches the sql schema

However, when I split the string using `string.split()` (or `re.split()`) all the elements of the returned list are of type "string". So my question is, how can I retain the type of the input after splitting?

thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "split the input text," its already comma separated

Comment: I think you missed the last comma in your csv line

Comment: I don't think that's possible. From reading a file you can't determine of something is a String or an int, etc.

Comment: The best you can probably do is use a heuristic to decide how to parse. For example, something in quotes in the original file should be interpreted as a `varchar`, etc..

Comment: How are you reading in your line/file?

Answer (score 1):

```
def try_cast( val ):
    try:
        if float(val) - int(val) > 0.01:
            return float(val)
        return int(val)
    except:
        return val

import csv
from functools import partial
fname = "test.csv"
cast_row_map = partial(map,try_cast)
data = map(cast_row_map,csv.reader(open(fname)))
```

might do what you want

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer by @JoranBeasley would work.  However, the whole use of "partial" and that call to "map()" is probably a bit opaque for a beginners.

That said, note that "try_cast" can be enhanced to "look for" data of any types, such as this:

```
import datetime
def try_cast(val):
    try:
        format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        return datetime.strptime(val, format)
    except:
        # looks like it is not a date
        pass
    try:
        # I prefer this test over Joran's
        if float(val) == int(val):
            return int(val)
        return float(val)
    except:
        # looks like it is not an int or float either
        return val
```